# Computed observable when using JSON in knockout

Tags: c#, knockout.js

I am after some knockout advice. I have already posted on this issue, but my understanding has changed so I am reposting.

I have the following code:

```
function updateViewModel() {
    if (typeof groupId == 'undefined') {
        groupId = getDefaultGroupId();
    }

    $.getJSON("api/livestatusgroup/children/" + groupId)
        .done(function (data) {
            ko.mapping.fromJS(data, liveStatusViewModel.groups);
            groupsLoaded();
        });

    $.getJSON("api/livestatusgroup/resources/" + groupId)
        .done(function(data) {
            ko.mapping.fromJS(data, liveStatusViewModel.resources);
            resourcesLoaded();
        });

    this.resourceImagePath = ko.computed(function () {
        return "../Image/" + this.resourceID();
    }, this);
}


function ViewModel() {
    var self = this;
    self.resources = ko.mapping.fromJS([]);
    self.groups = ko.mapping.fromJS([]);
}
```

I am loading my view model using JSON as you can see, but I am having trouble with the resourceID() method. I am not sure how to write the method that will replace the this.resourceID() with the resource ID (for example, ../Image/1). I have tried using a computed observer like this:

```
    liveStatusViewModel.resources.resourceID() = ko.computed(function() {
        return this.ResID;
    }, liveStatusViewModel);
```

...but that didn't work. Can anyone help me out? I have looked all over the interweb, including on Stack Overflow, but no luck. It's a real stumbling block!

**Further work**

I have just tried changing the way I append the /Image/xx to the image src, like this:

```
    function resourceImagePath(resourceId) {
        return "/Images/" + resourceId;
    }
```

with the following HTML markup

```
<div class="icon" id="resourceIcon" runat="server"><img data-bind="attr: { src: resourceImagePath(ResourceId) }" alt=""/></div>
```

This does not work. Annoyingly, the function resourceImagePath above rewritten like this:

```
    function resourceImagePath(resourceId) {
        return "/Images/1";
    }
```

with the image id hard-coded for testing, works absolutely fine.

Ideally I'd like to know how to make the resource ID in my JSON observable.

Anyone have any other ideas?

Thanks, Mark

Comment: I asked in your previous question, and will ask once again: Could you please show us full code of model, containing ResID, and the code where you call `updateViewModel()`. By the way, if your `resourceID()` is declared inside liveStatusViewModel, why do you expect it accessible as this.resourceID() from `updateViewModel` function?

Comment: I don't have the code for the model, it is being populated using JSON. I call updateViewModel() from $(document).ready function.

Answer (score 0):

I think your structure is incorrect because the computed function "resourceImagePath" should be a definition of an individual resource.

I realize you probably want to use that mapping plugin, but in my experience I found I have more flexibility when I map manually.  It's not fun, but you do it once and move on.

Here is how I would approach this.  I have not tested it at all.

1. Define your view models ("resource", "groups", "viewModel";
   including    computed variables)
2. Call viewModel.Initialize function on document load
3. When initializing loop through JSON results (i.e. "data") calls to gather data and
   create new instances of your Javascript objects (i.e. "resource", "groups")

   ```
   // global variable
   var groupId;


   // define view models
   var resource = function(resourceID){
       var self = this;

       self.resourceID() = ko.observable(resourceID);

       self.resourceImagePath = ko.computed(function () {
               return "../Image/" + self.resourceID();
       }, self);
   }

   // define group
   var group = function(groupId){
       var self = this;
       self.groupID() = ko.observable(groupId);
   }

   var viewModel = function() {
           var self = this;
           self.resources = ko.observableArray([]);
           self.groups = ko.observableArray([]);

           self.Initialize = function(){

               if (typeof groupId == 'undefined') {
                       groupId = getDefaultGroupId();
               }

               $.getJSON("api/livestatusgroup/children/" + groupId)
                       .done(function (data) {
                               for(var i = 0, j = data.length; i< j; i++){
                                   self.groups.push(new group(data[i].groupID))                            
                               }                                                       
                               groupsLoaded();
                       });

               $.getJSON("api/livestatusgroup/resources/" + groupId)
                       .done(function(data) {
                               for(var i = 0, j = data.length; i< j; i++){
                                   self.resources.push(new resource(data[i].resourceID))                           
                               }                                                       
                               resourcesLoaded();
                       });     

           }

   }


   var vmContext;
   $(function () {
       vm = new viewModel();
       vm.Initialize();
   });
   ```

Answer (score 0):

From a glance, I see a couple of potential issue.

```
<img data-bind="attr: { src: resourceImagePath(ResourceId) }" />
```

the issue here is that you are not resolving the observable when calling the resouceImagePath function. You can only use the observable without parenthesis when it is being directly called, as in

```
<img data-bind="attr: { src: SourceObservable }" />
```

So, the correct way to write it would be

```
<img data-bind="attr: { src: resourceImagePath(ResourceId()) }" />
```

Also, your computed ResourceID was not being assigned correctly.

```
liveStatusViewModel.resources.resourceID() = ko.computed(function() {
    return this.ResID;
}, liveStatusViewModel);
```

Here, you add paranthesis on the resourceID, which attempts to resolve the function, while also attempting to assign a value on the right-hand of the expression. This isn't valid JavaScript. Once you remove the parenthesis, it should work.

```
liveStatusViewModel.resources.resourceID = ko.computed(function() {
    return this.ResID;
}, liveStatusViewModel);
```

As for the rest of your post, I'm not really understanding what it is that you're trying to do, so this is the best answer I can give. I'm not sure if you want to assign the resourceID to each resource on liveStatusViewModel.resources, or if you want to add one computed on the liveStatusViewModel.resources object. If you clarify, I will be able to answer further.